# using test user in testing facebook apps

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

If I'm logged in with my real account, I can get all data I need.

If I'm logged in as a test user, the application authorization (canvasAuthorization) fails for the test user.

If I try to login using the test user's email and password, I get that account does not exist.

```
    user:
{
   "id": "499304595",
   "access_token": "217288868300629|2.****<removed***>.1305802800.0-499304595|gJYycHQgDO1VSYXCvDqFjHZeDV0",
   "login_url": "https://www.facebook.com/platform/test_account_login.php?user_id=499304595&n=BVSAcsDrBhiPIQZ",
   "email": "ucaibnh_vijayvergiyaberg\u0040tfbnw.net",
   "password": "734921974"
}
```

How do you use test users? I don't want to fill my wall with testing posts:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasted too many hours messing around with test accounts before finally deciding to manually create a real account that I use like a test account.

I love the idea of real test accounts, and I hope the system matures quickly, but until that day using a real account that isn't your actual account is the best method I know for getting work done (assuming you aren't doing automated or large scale testing, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked that you don't have the Sandbox enabled for that application?

Answer (score 0):

I think you ran into a facebook [bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17838) that has already been tackled.
Normally it should have worked.